# Error when trying to referance .net core Class library from Web app ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

So it sounds like a trivial task, I just want to use common code from my class library in both my web api and webapp but I am unable to reference the class library from my webapp projects, so I made a clean project to test it out.
I have 3 projects:ClassLib1, ClassLib2, WebApp
I am able to reference ClassLib1 From ClassLib2 but I cannot referance either Class librarys from the webapp project
Here are my project.json's

ClassLib1

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
    }
  }
}
```

ClassLib2 is exactly the same as ClassLib1

Web App

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "ClassLib1": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

SS showing using ClassLib1 in ClassLib2 successfully

[image]

SS showing error in webapp when trying to use ClassLib1

[image]

The error when moused over is `cannot resolve symbol 'ClassFromLib1'

Edit: I just noticed that if I change the web app to use `netstandard1.5` from `netcoreapp1.0` I can then referance code between the projects.
Should I do this? are there any downside by changing the framework in targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that the issue I was having was with Resharper. It was making the text red and giving me the errors, it did actually build and work fine but I just didn't see past the red text.

Comment: I experience the exact same behavior. Everything builds fine, but even if I disable the R# extension, the editor cannot properly resolve symbols defined by class libraries. Navigating to the symbol under the cursor does not work either...